# How to use rating bar without intermediate values?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to get rating value without intermediate values like 4.5,3.5 etc
what I want is to get a rating like 4,5 etc.
right now my rating bar is like this

[image]

Comment: set stepsize = 1 in xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `xml` add this for the `ratingbar`

```
android:stepSize="1"
```